# Configure log4j to log filenames without .java filetype

Tags: xml, layout, configuration, log4j

I would like to log class names (excluding package prefix) as well as methods in the following way:

```
<className>.<methodName>
```

Currently my xml layout for this is

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p [%t] (%F.%M) - %m%n" />
</layout>
```

which returns a filename that includes the .java file type.

**Is there some way to configure log4j so that it will remove the .java from the filename?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the class name, then you should consider the %C conversion character, as described in the [Javadoc for PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html).

For instance, to specify the unqualified class name:

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p [%t] (%C{1}.%M) - %m%n" />
</layout>
```

Note the usage of the {1} qualifier, which designates the first rightmost component of the fully qualified class name.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Apologies - was on my phone and had no option to accept it at the time :)